# Change typo3 language according to domain

Tags: multilingual, typo3-10.x

I'm using Typo3 10
I have 2 domains foobar.com and foobar.fr

I have a multilanguage site working with a single pagetree (using Typo3 multilanguage ability)
I wish people using the .fr domain landed on the .fr language of the site and people using the .com landed on the English version.

How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the SiteConfiguration:

I setup a simple example page with DDEV to test this

Here's my example siteconfiguration:

```
base: 'https://en.ddev.site/'
languages:
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-us
    direction: ltr
    flag: us
  -
    title: French
    enabled: true
    base: 'https://fr.ddev.site/'
    typo3Language: fr
    locale: fr_FR.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: fr
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: fr-FR
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: fr
    languageId: 1
  -
    title: Spanish
    enabled: true
    base: 'https://es.ddev.site/'
    typo3Language: es
    locale: es_ES.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: es
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: es-ES
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: es
    languageId: 2
rootPageId: 1
websiteTitle: 'my Test Page'
```

For the frontend I simply created a typoscript TEXT

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = Hello English (Default)

[siteLanguage("languageId") == "1"]
    page.10.value = Bonjour Francais
[siteLanguage("languageId") == "2"]
    page.10.value = Hola Espanol
[end]
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Index.html

In my example I use sub domains, but it will also work with TLD